# Scipy optimization : Constrains placed on both inputs and outputs

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

Let's consider a smooth(continuous) analytical function that is not known a priori. (a black-box function)

This function accepts an array of tuples and spits out a few scalers let's say **A**,**B** and **C**.
One mandatory requirement of this function is that it only accepts arrays with increasing **0th index** values.

For example:
This works.
`[ (0,1) (1,20) (2,15) (4,25) (5,30) ]`

But this won't.
`[ (0,1) (2,20) (1,15) (4,25) (5,30) ]`

My question is, How do I write a constraint function such that,

- The above requirement is met &
- A > some const
- C < come const
- Ideally works with a gradient-based method available in scipy instead of GA based method.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you sort before evaluate? Sometimes this trick can help.

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks for the reply. But as per my understanding, that won't help because of 2 reasons. The optimizer itself selects the values. And even somehow I do the value selection the jacobian will be messed up after sorting and the direction taken for the next step will be incorrect. isnt it

Comment: (1) Sure. That is rather obvious.Just sort (a copy of) X . (2) Just map the gradients back. (Keep track of how the order changes)

Comment: (3) of course you can add a bunch of constraints like `x(1,1) <= x(2,1)`. Unfortunately, the constrained NLP solvers in scipy are not very sophisticated.

Comment: (3a) and the solver will still want to evaluate infeasible points. So these constraints do not prevent unordered X to be passed on.

Comment: You mentioned black box functions. They typically don't have gradients. In case you do finite differences you don't need to map gradients back.